# Power BI export to PDF automation

Tags: office365, powerbi, office365-apps, power-automate

So my company won't pay out for Power BI to every user in the business.

I have Power BI Pro, I have a report that I wish to create a PDF copy and sent to various recipients.

Problem is that I need the data to update to each recipient which has their own data set, a row of data in an excel file, and then a PDF created and emailed out and loop back to the next recipient.

I'm trying to use MS Flow to do this with little luck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The [Power BI API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) does not seem to support PDF exports, so I am afraid automating through Power BI is impossible. You could probably look at UI automation (e.g. [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) or a [mouse recording software](https://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/mouse-recorder/)).

Comment: This seems as stupidity breaking to two instances:1. Crystal reporting 2. BI
From what I know there is no way to do that, welcome to 21 century

Comment: Sorry but Power BI is not meant or developed to allow you to do that. If you manage to do that somehow, you are breaking the policies. I suggest Excel dashboard with a bit of VBA on it to update the data & send out the Emails automatically etc.,

Comment: For anyone to track this feature in the [PowerBI Idea Page](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/35066698-export-to-pdf-via-power-bi-embedded-api)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file-in-group Looks like this is now available.